# Searching for the word "Unsubscribe" as a hyperlink in an email

Tags: c#, regex, email, hyperlink

I am trying to look through emails in a folder and determine if they contain the word ***'Unsubscribe'*** as a hyperlink. Currently I am looking at the body of the Item and searching for the word unsubscribe by doing

```
if (body.Contains("Unsubscribe"))
```

I was wondering how to search for a hyperlink with a specified word. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you're looking for a hyperlink with the word "Unsubscribe" in it, you can use the following regex:

`<a.*?href.*?>[\S]*?[uU]nsubscribe.*[\S]</a>`

This will search for any hyperlink with "unsubscribe" or "Unsubscribe" somewhere in it.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/iu0rfX/2)

Comment: In C# regex, you don't need to escape '/'. It has no special meaning.

Comment: @NickReed so would I have to initialize as such: Regex url = new Regex(<a.*?href.*?>[\s\S]*?[uU]nsubscribe.*[\s\S]<\/a>) then, if (url.Matches(body))

Comment: I would put quotes around the regex when initializing it, i.e. `Regex url = new Regex("<a.*?href.*?>[\s\S]*?[uU]nsubscribe.*[\s\S]</a>")` - also, you don't need the `\ ` in the closing `<a>` tag, that was a typo on my part. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.8) for more info.

Comment: @NickReed thanks for the help so far. Are the '\' in \s\S needed? it is underlined in red saying "unrecognized escape sequence"

Comment: Try putting an @ in front of the string: `Regex url = new Regex(@"<a.*?href.*?>[\s\S]*?[uU]nsubscribe.*[\s\S]</a>")` OR using double-slashes to escape the escape characters `Regex url = new Regex("<a.*?href.*?>[\\s\\S]*?[uU]nsubscribe.*[\\s\S]</a>")`

Comment: @NickReed @ seemed to work, I will test and let you know

Comment: @NickReed I'm using the regex to do the following: look through the body of each email and search for "unsubscribe" as a hyperlink. In my code I have, Match match = url.Match(body). if(match.Success), count++. The program seems to run very slow now and eventually stops or gets stuck on an email. Any advice?

Comment: Sounds like the regex is suffering from excessive backtracking. [Try adding a timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices#Timeouts) to your regex - that should help with performance.

Comment: @NickReed what regex options should I be using. Currently using .Compiled, .IgnoreCase, .Singleline

Comment: I think those options are fine. As an experiment, also consider trying this: `<a.*?href.*?>[\S]*?[uU]nsubscribe.*[\S]</a>`. This removes multi-line matching, which is likely causing issues. In hindsight, it was probably a bad idea for me to add it - who uses multi-line <a> tags?

Comment: @NickReed took some time but i got it to work. Thanks so much. Only problem now is that it is only pulling 6,000 emails when it should be pulling more (the whole folder, 28,000)

Comment: Maybe there's a cap on how many emails it can pull at one time, I think that's almost certainly related to something else in the code. Regardless, very glad you got it working. Please remember to accept the answer if it meets the needs of your question.

Comment: Just a note that many spammers now just put the unsubscribe URL as plain text (without an anchor tag) even in the HTML version of the email. They rely on the email client to convert it to a hyperlink. They're trying to make it harder for people to create scripts that automatically unsubscribe, and also hoping many clients won't properly convert the link.